# Tooltip is invisible on javascript graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tooltip

I have an issue and I really need your help.
I have a realtime graph that the data and time is generated randomly on it and want to make a tooltip to show time and value on that point on the path when the graph moves. That is what I have but the tooltip is not shown on my graph! http://jsfiddle.net/QBDGB/59/ That is what I have added to "path1" in roder to show the tooltip on it:

```
   //tooltip

 var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
.attr("class", "tooltip")
.style("opacity", 0);

  var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div")   
.attr("class", "tooltip")               
.style("opacity", 0);

  var blueCircles = svg.selectAll("path1")
    .data(data1s)
       .on("mouseover", function(d ,i) {
         tooltip.transition()
         .duration(650)
         .style("opacity", .9);
         tooltip.html(formatTime(new Date(d.time)) + "<br/>" + d.value)
         .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
       .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
        })
       .on("mouseout", function(d ,i ) {
            div.transition()
                .duration(650)
                .style("opacity", 0);
        });
```

Any idea or similar example of work for realtime javascript graph with tooltip?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I got the tooltip to show up. http://jsfiddle.net/QBDGB/67/

Here's what I changed and why:

```
var blueCircles = svg.selectAll(".line1")
    //.data(data1s)
```

You were passing "path1" as the selector. "path1" is the name of the variable, not the name of the class, you need to select for class, id, or tag name. Not variable name. A selector with no preceding character is selecting for the tag name ("a", "body", "head", etc.) but a preceding "." selects for the class. Which is what it looks like you were trying to do.

I removed the ".data" call because you already included the data here:

```
var path1 = svg.append("g")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
    .append("path")
    .data([data1s])
    .attr("class", "line1");
```

See the d3 API on selections for more https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer,it was great:) http://jsfiddle.net/QBDGB/79/ is what I made based on ur recommendation but as you can see it doesnot show the correct value at each point when the cursor moves along the graph.if u click once on the graph it get pause and you can see that by moving the cursor the value is static and it shows the last generated value not the value at each point. That is my another attempt and I made the tooltip with circles: http://jsfiddle.net/QBDGB/53/ it shows the value and time correctly but the circles move silly.do u have idea of how to remove the circles?

Comment: There are some other ways to make tooltips. One is appending a [title](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/title). Another way that provides more flexibility is [tipsy](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/)